# Notification when a parameter in param server is changed

Tags: ros, parameter

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is there any C++ utility to notice if a parameter in param server has changed instead of storing the value and keep checking it for changes continuously?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9867/notification-when-a-parameter-in-param-server-is-changed/) by [Victor Lopez](https://answers.ros.org/users/395/victor-lopez/) on ROS Answers with karma: 651 on 2011-05-02

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Victor Lopez](https://answers.ros.org/users/395/victor-lopez/) on 2011-05-03**:
I'll have a look at it, but it is marked as unstable so I'm not sure it is resilient enough for what I need.

**Comment by [Victor Lopez](https://answers.ros.org/users/395/victor-lopez/) on 2011-05-03**:
I'll have a look at it, but it is marked as unstable so I'm not sure it is resilient enough for what I need. I have a workaround, which is a thread that queries the parameter I'm watching and reports if it has been changed.

**Comment by [Felix Endres](https://answers.ros.org/users/113/felix-endres/) on 2011-05-02**:
A colleague of mine used it with python and c++

**Comment by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) on 2011-05-02**:
Yes, but dynamic_reconfigure only works with Python, right?

**Comment by [Felix Endres](https://answers.ros.org/users/113/felix-endres/) on 2011-05-02**:
If you expect changes during runtime, maybe you should use dynamic_reconfigure instead of the parameter server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You could periodically call `getParamCached()`. It caches the value locally and subscribes to the parameter server for notification in the event of updates. So, the polling overhead is minimal.

Or, use `dynamic_reconfigure`. Even though it's marked unstable, the basic interfaces are widely used and will probably be preserved in future distributions.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2011-05-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Asomerville](https://answers.ros.org/users/351/asomerville/) on 2011-05-05**:
I don't know if I'm going nuts, but when I looked in the param.cpp code (in diamondback), I couldn't find where the cached params were being updated. Instead it looks for all the world like the normal params are being updated and the cached ones are not.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It doesn't appear to be a conventionally exposed interface for doing so, *and it's probably not a recommended route*, but if you have a look in **`stacks/ros_comm/clients/cpp/roscpp/src/libros`** you'll find **`param.cpp`** where ros does it's parameter handling for each node. *(edit)* You can try to emulate what they did.

In:

```
   void init(const M_string& remappings)
```

you'll see that they set up a callback:

```
   XMLRPCManager::instance()->bind("paramUpdate", paramUpdateCallback);
```

Which is used to update the local parameter table. You might be able to set up your own callback to do this, but I'm unsure if it would interfere with the node's own parameter updating.

The signature of the callback looks like this btw:

```
    void callback(XmlRpc::XmlRpcValue& params, XmlRpc::XmlRpcValue& result)
```

You can look at **`param.cpp`** for details on how to use the arguments.

---

Originally posted by [Asomerville](https://answers.ros.org/users/351/asomerville/) with karma: 2743 on 2011-05-04

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Victor Lopez](https://answers.ros.org/users/395/victor-lopez/) on 2011-05-05**:
You're right, sorry I misunderstood you. Certainly it might interfere with normal param updating, I think I'll use a less intrusive approach.

**Comment by [Asomerville](https://answers.ros.org/users/351/asomerville/) on 2011-05-05**:
You don't need to change param.cpp to use this, simply use the same method it does to attach a callback. I only say not conventionally exposed because I've not ever seen the use of XMLRPCManager discussed in any ros documentation.

**Comment by [Victor Lopez](https://answers.ros.org/users/395/victor-lopez/) on 2011-05-05**:
I was looking for something more standard because changing param.cpp is not an option.

**Comment by [Mate Wolfram](https://answers.ros.org/users/402/mate-wolfram/) on 2013-06-02**:
I tried binding to the same callback, but the program tends to gets stuck after this call, and I never receive a callback. If I first unbind the original callback method and then bind my implementation, it works, but that's too intrusive. Did anyone experience the same problem?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I was looking for a way to accomplish this without the useful but cumbersome dynamic_reconfigure package as I think we have enough things to deal with, just considering ROS messages/actions/services, launch files (that support YAML syntax in XML...) and catkin specific CMakeLists file without adding another layer of complexity which is often unneeded.

So here is my working but ***flawed** example (I followed Asormeville's hints):

```
#include <ros/ros.h>
#include <ros/xmlrpc_manager.h>
#include <std_msgs/String.h>

void callback(XmlRpc::XmlRpcValue& params, XmlRpc::XmlRpcValue& result)
{
    ROS_ERROR("Updated parameters!");
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    XmlRpc::XmlRpcValue params, result, payload;

    ros::init(argc, argv, "test_node");

    ros::NodeHandle nh;

    ros::XMLRPCManager::instance()->unbind("paramUpdate");
    ros::XMLRPCManager::instance()->bind("paramUpdate", callback);
    
    ros::param::set("~test_param", true);

    ROS_INFO("Created new parameter through XmlRpc API call.");

    params[0] = ros::this_node::getName();
    params[1] = ros::XMLRPCManager::instance()->getServerURI();
    params[2] = ros::names::resolve(std::string("~test_param"));

    if (ros::master::execute("subscribeParam", params, result, payload, false)) {
        ROS_INFO("Subscribed to parameter.");
    }
    else {
        ROS_ERROR("Failed to subscribe to the parameter.");
    }

    while (ros::ok()) {
        ros::spinOnce();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The next steps would be to have a specific callback per parameter.
But I don't know if that would be possible and it would begin to look like Publishers/Subscribers mechanisms.

*** The ROS node redefining this callback won't be able to use the *ros::param::getCached()* function anymore.**

---

Originally posted by [phlf](https://answers.ros.org/users/27346/phlf/) with karma: 21 on 2016-06-30

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [*andrei*](https://answers.ros.org/users/57604/_andrei_/) on 2022-04-06**:
At first, thank you for the information sharing. I think this answer is the closest to the goal.

It is possible to use `getCached` function, you just need to make a hack of declaring `ros::param::paramUpdateCallback`, and then calling it in your custom callback. I checked it, the cache is filled this way.

Probably it's possible to implement individual subscribers for each parameters by adding sub-callbacks inside the main callback. But I'm already happy with your solution.

**Comment by [phlf](https://answers.ros.org/users/27346/phlf/) on 2022-04-06**:
Happy if my answer may have helped someone six years later ;) I did not follow ROS development closely so there may me a more effective way to do the same kind of things with ROS2 (though I am not sure there is still a concept of a parameter server)